# SSRS report just hangs when upgrading from VS 2012 32-bit to VS 2022 64-bit

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to upgrade our companies SSRS reports to the latest version of Visual Studio to ensure continuity. When I try to open a report it just hangs.
[image: opening file progress]

**Old Visual studio version**

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Integrated)
Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: IDE Standard

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012

Microsoft Visual Basic 2012

Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2012

Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer
Version 11.0.3436.0

Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 11.0.3436.0

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers
Version 11.0.3436.0

**New Visual Studio version**

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022
Version 17.5.3
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.5.3+33516.290
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

Installed Version: Enterprise

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2022

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2022

Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools   17.2.40119.0

Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 16.0.5131.0

Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers
Version 16.0.20309.0

Is there anything else that I need to install or setting that I need to change?

Comment: Just an idea... create a new report for your current version.. open it it notepad (its only an XML file) and open your old report in notepad. Compare the header section.. see if you can copy and paste the header section from the new one to your current one.. save and then open again to see if it works.

Comment: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily" MustUnderstand="df">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
```

Comment: so.. am i supposed to do something with that? You were meant to compare the headers and see what's different!